# I can't return a value in define function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to make a fighting system which works on its own and all I gotta do is input the values, though I get a problem at the end:

```
import time
import random
hp=80
atk1=5
atk2=7
mp=40
smite1=12
smite2=15
def     fmode(atkf1,atkf2,enemyatk1,enemyatk2,enemy,enemyhp,xp):
 hpf=hp
 mpf=mp
 while True:
  if enemyhp>0:
   yt=0
   print("The "+str(enemy)+" attacks!")
   time.sleep(1)
   dmg=random.randint(enemyatk1,enemyatk2)
   hpf=hpf-dmg
   print("The "+str(enemy)+" hit you for "+str(dmg))
   time.sleep(1)
   print("You are at "+str(hpf)+"hp")
   time.sleep(1)
   print("Your turn")
   time.sleep(1)
   yt=1
   print("1)Attack "+" 2)Ability")
   while True:
    if yt==1:
     inpy=input("Select:")
     if inpy=="1":
      dmg=random.randint(atkf1,atkf2)
      print("You hit the "+str(enemy)+" for "+str(dmg)+"hp")
      enemyhp=enemyhp-dmg
      time.sleep(1)
      print("The "+str(enemy)+" is at "+str(enemyhp)+"hp")
      time.sleep(1)
      yt=0
      break
     if inpy=="2":
      print("1)Backstab "+" 2)Heal "+str(mpf)+" mana left")
      while True:
       inpy1=input("Select:")
       if inpy1=="1":
        dmg=random.randint(smite1,smite2)
        enemyhp=enemyhp-dmg
        mpf=mpf-15
        print("You stab the "+str(enemy)+" for "+str(dmg))
        time.sleep(1)
        print("The "+str(enemy)+" is at "+str(enemyhp)+"hp")
        time.sleep(1)
        yt=0
        break
    if yt==0:
     break
  if enemyhp<=0:
   print("The "+str(enemy)+" has been defeated.")
   time.sleep(1)
   print(str(xp)+"XP gained")
   time.sleep(1)
   return hpf,mpf
fmode(5,7,1,3,"rat",20,15)
print(hpf)
print(mpf)
```

I want to make it so at the end it returns hpf, or better yet hp, so after the fight is over, the hp and mp are saved, though I can't get why it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the return when you call your `fmode` function:

```
hpf, mpf = fmode(5,7,1,3,"rat",20,15)
```

Comment: I didn't think about assigning hpf and mpf to fmode...but that apparently works.Thank you.

Comment: @Rain because the vars hpf and mpf are declared inside the function fmode, you don't have access to them when you want to print them. You did the right thing by returning them in the function - you just needed something to save them in the current scope so your prints would work. These are just two more vars and could be named anything (it would still work even if wasn't hpf/mpf)

Comment: @Rain please accept as the answer if this helped you find a solution!

Comment: Yeah,I'm new to the site,not used to doing stuff like that.I think i voted it as an answer.Also,what's up with the dislikes?

Answer (score 0):

You are only returning values `if enemyhp < = 0`, and even then you are not saving the return values:

```
hpf, mpf = fmode(5,7,1,3,"rat",20,15)
print(hpf)
print(mpf)
```

Comment: I didn't think about assigning hpf and mpf to fmode...but that apparently works.Thank you.